# Which network devices should I use in a small office network for ~200 users?

Tags: cisco, switch, router, ethernet, lan

I need to create a (fictional) network for a 3 storey office building. According to the EU-norms there should be 2 RJ-45 sockets for 10m2 of the office space. I've already designed structured cabling, so I know that there will be 58 RJ-45 sockets on each floor. I decided that this is going to be a Gigabit ethernet in the building, because this would give ca. 20Mb/s per socket which is enough for this project.

Now I need to choose devices for this project. From what I've learned I decided that there should be one MDF on the ground floor and IDF's on other floors. 
In the MDF I need a router which would handle 4Gb/s and a core switch from which the network will be distributed to the IDFs on the other floors.
In IDFs I need two routers with 48 ports (since I haven't found anything with more ports).

I've tried to pick devices by myself, but for a noob like me it's a little bit like magic. I've picked following devices, but I guess that these are much too expensive and "too good" for this network.

- Switches for IDFs: 2xCisco WS-C3650-48TS-S
- Switch for MDF: Cisco
  WS-C3650-48TQ-S
- Router for MDF: Cisco Catalys 6503-E

How can I optimize the cost of this network and which devices (or devices families) I should pick from?

Comment: "shopping" questions are off-topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Access: 4x (or 5x) Cisco WS-C2960X-48TS-LL
Core: 2x Cisco WS-C3850-12S-E
SFPs: double the uplink count
deploy aqua colored OM3-OM4 fiber between floors for future 10G

Comment: And what about a router?

Comment: That 3850 is a multi-layer switch and has routing capabilities.

Comment: Assuming that I have a fiber form the ISP, where should it be connected? To one of the Cisco WS-C3850-12S-E? Why do I need two core switches?

Comment: Moreover, why do I need to connect core switch to other switches with two fiber cables for each connection?

Comment: Redundant uplinks between switches is recommended.  The 3850-12's stack with a special stacking cable so no uplinks between those two.  Your ISP will hand you copper.  Plug that into a security appliance such as a NGFW like ASA w FirePower or your favorite NGFW security appliance.